# fail2ban on centos 8 using iptables instead of firewalld

Tags: fail2ban, firewalld

I have a question about fail2ban behavior and hope you could help to clarify.  thanks in advance.

So I had fail2ban running on a CentOS 8 server successfully but it just occurred to me recently that on this centOS server, it uses firewalld and has no iptables service.  I know some documentation suggest to use firewallcmd-ipset, but on my jail.conf, the **banaction** is to use "iptables-multiport" and it has obviously been working correctly.  Maybe firewalld read iptables rules in the background? Any explanation of this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Firewalld is just an interface on top of iptables.